# How to shift bits between two different register?

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-shift, extended-precision

I have two registers,R1 and R2. I need a shift operation between them. Is there any instruction for this operation or should I follow a different path? Actually, I can obtain the less significant digit of R1 by using AND instruction but, I also can shift R2 by using ASR instruction,but I can't append that digit to the most significant part of R2.

[image: Shift between registers]

Comment: In general, you can shift it left to the MSB position, shift your target right, then apply the MSB with a bitwise `OR`. On ARM, you can use `ASR` to get the LSB into the carry then `RRX` to shift that into the destination.

Comment: you are genius,thanks. Can i ask you something, i am new here. Why didn't you answer it, because that worked. Thanks again.(I meant you commented not answered. Isn't it good for you? You get points)

Comment: Yes,how can't i think that. Latter would be better for the solution.

Comment: If you want to shift *multiple* bits between registers, it's more efficient to do them all at once with an OR.  Have a look at how compilers implement `x >> 10` or something for `uint64_t x`, on 32-bit ARM.  https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Hi Peter Cordes, thanks for your answer OR really worked. I will check the link.

Comment: Depending on where the bits you want are, and where you want them to go, a combination of `ubfx` and `bfi` might work better than shifting, if your ARM implementation has these instructions.